# Does NFS copy files to NFS server, or does it share files locally?

Tags: linux, file-transfer, nfs

Bit of an outline: basically I'm running a Raspberry Pi to save videos from a webcam, but naturally the Pi doesn't have too much space, so I've set up a NFS server. Does the directory on the Raspberry Pi (the client) keep the files stored locally if I save the video files to that directory, or does it simply save them to the hard drive of the NFS server?

Naturally, I'm hoping it's not saving them locally on the Pi. Otherwise it will very quickly run out of space!

Answer (score 3):

If you have created an NFS share on the NFS server and mounted it on the client, of course the files will be stored in the server's hard disk although it might look from a perceptual point of view that they are stored in a directory of the client's hard disk. In any case make sure that the share is properly mounted by issuing a mount comand at the client's command line or by simply checking the files are indeed being stored in the server's hard disk from the server's command line.

One of the most common mistakes made by novices is believing to have mounted the remote FS via NFS when they have not. Then all files start to be stored in the local mount directory instead of on the server.

Always check that your remote NFS FS is indeed mounted locally by issuing the **mount** command alone, it will show a list of the mounted file systems, your NFS share should appear on the list.

Comment: Just to confirm, if the files are saved to the NFS server, via the client, they won't be stored locally as well on the client-side? (I always thought that it would be on the server hard disk, but needed to make sure as I'm writing a little script that would be utterly pointless if it did store the files locally too!)

Comment: Interesting thing about Linux, you can mount an external or remote server as if it is a directory on the local server (the raspberry pi). So if you had your NFS server mounted on the /mnt/cam, then as far as linux (or pi) is concerned, it is simply saving all videos to a local folder /mnt/cam while it is actually pointing to a remote host. So in this case, Daniel answer above is accurate.